# Regular expression that matches values after meetting some keyword

Tags: python, regex

I have some path separated by spaces, but not separated by \s/\s i.e: space, slash, space

val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue aaa / bbb ccc / ddd eee / fff

- 1st element: val1 / val2
- 2nd element: val4 / val7
- 3rd element: keyword / somevalue
- 4th element: aaa / bbb
- 5th element: ccc / ddd
- 6th element: eee / fff

When I find the keyword with somevalue:

```
(keyword / [^/\s]*)
```

The only acceptable values after the above match can be aaa / bbb and ccc / ddd, no matter the order, no matter the duplications.

For example I should get a match for

1. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue aaa / bbb ccc / ddd
2. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue aaa / bbb
3. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue ccc / ddd
4. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue ccc / ddd aaa / bbb
5. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue ccc / ddd aaa / bbb ccc / ddd

Any other combination should return unmatch, for example:
When there is some extra 'element' after keyword / somevalue

1. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue aaa / bbb ccc / ddd eee / fff
2. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue eee / fff ccc / ddd
3. val1 / val2 val4 / val7 keyword / somevalue aaa / bbb zzz / yyy ccc / ddd

(...)

I should get unmatch.

Is it possible to achieve it with a regular expression?
I am trying to solve it with regex but I stuck.

Comment: No, it is not what I am looking for.
Programming language doesn't matter, but I added extra tag

Comment: Programming language DOES matter because not all languages use the same regex flavor. Therefore, a pattern that works in one language might not work with another.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, anyway thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try the following [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/C5dMMw/2):

```
keyword \/ \w+ ((?:aaa \/ bbb|ccc \/ ddd)(?: |$))+$
```

Where:

- `keyword` is your fixed keyword
- `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` and `ddd` are the ones to be matched literally
- `aaa \/ bbb` is the first allowed couple and `ccc \/ ddd` is the second one
- `(?: |$)` checks, whether a couple is followed with an empty space or the end of a line `$`.

I have to stress out that it's highly recommended to use a programming language for the extraction. You should split the string and examine the partitions.

Comment: Thanks for regex it's working. It is not possible to use any programming language in this case.

Comment: Well that's mysterious. In what scenario can the following be true? a) use regex to solve a problem, and b) NOT use a programming language to solve the problem?